# Can't crack the code to remove an extra *

Tags: python

I have attached a trimmed down version of the program. The issue I'm having is when I print N there is an extra * at the end that I haven't managed to remove from the code. I've been trying for hours now but I just can't seem to crack it.

I've changed +'s to -'s and vice versa. I've tried increasing and decreasing values. All I've managed to do is warp my output, but the extra * remains.

Program:-

```
def is_valid_word(word):
    valid_letters = set("ABNOTY")
    return all(letter in valid_letters for letter in word)

size=7

def get_pattern(letter, size):
    # Define patterns for each letter based on the specified size
    patterns = {
        'N': [" " + "*" + " " * (size - 2) + "*"] + [" " + "*" + " " * (i - 1) + "*" + " " * (size - i - 2) + "*" + " " for i in range(1, size)],

    }
    
    return patterns.get(letter, ["Invalid"])

def main():
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop): ")

        if word.upper() == "END":
            break

        if not is_valid_word(word):
            print("Error: Invalid input. Please enter a valid word.")
            continue

        letter_patterns = [get_pattern(letter, size) for letter in word]

        for i in range(size):
            for pattern in letter_patterns:
                print(pattern[i], end=" ")
            print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I am currently printing is
[Output with extra * on bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bobB.png)

Comment: If I run your code it fails with `IndexError: list index out of range` at `print(pattern[i], end=" ")`.

Comment: @Paul Did you try to enter more than one `N`? There is another one issue with indentation in the output/rendering (for following letters).

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Thanks for the heads up. I will amend my code to avoid skewing further outputs!

Answer (score 0):

to print N you currently have 1 "pattern" for 1st line, then another for the rest of them. And this fails for the last line, which obviously has same pattern as the first one.

Updating your `get_pattern` to this code will do the trick:

```
def get_pattern(letter, size):
    # Define patterns for each letter based on the specified size
    patterns = {
        'N': [" " + "*" + " " * (size - 2) + "*"] + [" " + "*" + " " * (i - 1) + "*" + " " * (size - i - 2) + "*" + " " for i in range(1, size - 1)] + [" " + "*" + " " * (size - 2) + "*"],

    }

    return patterns.get(letter, ["Invalid"])
```

output:

```
Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop): N
 *     * 
 **    *  
 * *   *  
 *  *  *  
 *   * *  
 *    **  
 *     * 
Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop):
```

Comment: Try to enter `NNN` on your version and see the output

Comment: @ilias-sp, Thank you so much! Something so simple.